# What is the best way to include php database data with HTML

Tags: php, html, postgresql

I am currently working on a website, i am quite new to this. I have established connection to my database with the connection.php file, but it seems quite hard to style a PHP file.
So i want to know:

1. Is there a smarter way to make a dropdown with data from a database and how would i include and syle the website then if it is still a .php file?
2. My preference would be to create a good looking website with HTML & CSS. But i don't know how to include my dropdown with data from the database?

As it is right now all are in one file, so it looks like this

Thank you in advance

**Index.php**

```
    <?php
    ini_set("display_errors", "On");
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    
    $host='database.****.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com';
    $db = '****';
    $port = 5432;
    $username = 'postgres';
    $password = '****';
    
    try {
      $conn = new PDO("pgsql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$db;user=$username;password=$password");
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Choose Category</h1>

<?php
$sql ="select * from products inner join category  on category.category_id = products.category";

//Prepare the select statement.
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

//Execute the statement.
$stmt->execute();

//Retrieve the rows using fetchAll.
$users = $stmt->fetchAll();
// show menu from dropdown 
?>
<select>
    <?php foreach($users as $user): ?>
        <option value="<?= $user['id']; ?>"><?= $user['name']; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want a "smarter" way, you can read up on the MVC pattern (for PHP). Or even smarter, use an existing framework. When it comes to styling, there's no difference from a normal HTML page since the PHP code is executed on the server and only returns the output to the client, which in the above code would be just the HTML.

Comment: Definitely recommend separating your code into an MVC (model, view, controller) pattern or using an already created framework. Makes it cleaner (which means easier to maintain) and does a lot of heavy lifting for you.

Comment: thanks guys i will take a look at that !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a much simpler way but I am going to give an example:
Suppose you have a php file:

connection.php:

```
<?php
function connect(){
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbname");
if(!$con)
die("Could not connect");
}

return $con;
}
?>
```

Now another file called getAll.php

```
<?php
require("connection.php");
$con=connect();
$getAll="select * from employees";
$res=mysqli_query($con,$getAll);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
echo "<option value='$row[firstname]'>$row['firstname']</option>"
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

?>

Now where you want to display the dropdown list:

Suppose a file called display.php

```
<html>
     <body>
          <select name="employee">
          <?php
          require("getAll.php");
          ?>
          </select>
     </body>
</html>
```

This is a simple way to get data from database and display them.

Comment: is it possible to have a HTML file, where my css is on. And then choose a dropdown which contain php with data from the database. Or do i have to do php sites.

Comment: To get data from database you have to create a php file not a html file. And still you can include css in it.

Comment: You can always treat a php file as if it was an html file.